# Facebook Likes not showing on Facebook page but show up on site

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hi I have a like box on my website scoreoid.net which already has 97 likes I'm using the Open Graph API however my Facebook is not showing the same amount of likes. I'm not sure why is it possible to have both the site and the Facebook company page match makes no sense that there different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You using [Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) social plugin, not the [Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/). This is very different things while first intended to be used for any URL second is for Facebook Pages only.

You have 97 likes for your site homepage (URL Like Button linked too), not for the Facebook Page

Answer (score 0):

Facebook pages like count is different from a website like count, as they are considered to be two separate objects.  The company I work for prefers to have two different counts for statistical analysis purposes.

For your website, you can see stats here:
`http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.scoreoid.net`

```
{
   "id": "http://www.scoreoid.net",
   "shares": 97,
   "comments": 4
}
```

For the facebook page, you can see stats here: `http://graph.facebook.com/245182948843019`

```
{
   "id": "245182948843019",
   "name": "Scoreoid",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/373193_245182948843019_842741787_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Scoreoid/245182948843019",
   "likes": 5,
   "category": "Software",
   "website": "http://www.scoreoid.net",
   "founded": "2011",
   "description": "Scoreoid, developed by game developers for game developers, is a non-restrictive, reliable and easy to use gaming platform designed to handle but not limited to scoring, leaderboards and game management, including advanced functions such as platform content awareness, for multi-platform games.",
   "about": "Scoreoid, developed by game developers for game developers, is a non-restrictive, reliable and easy to use gaming platform designed to handle but not limited to scoring, leaderboards and game management, including advanced functions.",
   "can_post": true
}
```

As you can see the id is different between the two, hence why separate statistics. However, I don't think there's a way to merge them together on facebook's side.  For statistical purposes you will have to call the graph for each object and sum up their like counts.

Comment: Thanks everyone, not sure what is better but I don't think it's good to go back now.